# Puppet - Automatic provisioning with Vagrant VMs

Tags: puppet, vagrant

I have three virtual machine that I have created using Vagrant. This virtual machine have as box ubuntu/trusty64. I have created all VMs in the same Vagrantfile as single project. To provision it, I have used Puppet. For now, the three vms use different manifests. I want to automate this process, when the manifests change. So, if I add one package to one manifest I want that without my intervention, vagrant detect that and re-provision VMs according with new changes in manifests files.

I'm very newbie in Vagrant and more in Puppet, for that, my question is:

¿is that possible?

This is the project that I am developing: https://github.com/jngd/puppet-tfg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant itself isn't going to be able to do this.  What you'll need is something like [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) to watch the manifests and do "something" when they change.  I wouldn't recommend completely reprovisioning the VM (`vagrant destroy; vagrant up`) on every change, because that way lies madness (it'll take a lot longer to run that it'll take you to make more edits), but running `vagrant ssh sudo puppet apply /etc/puppet` is certainly feasible.

Comment: Good one! The guard project seems very interesting and with it I think I can do what I'm proposing in this question. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Puppet user, but a CFEngine veteran. I did see that Puppet has an agent - puppet-agent that (can) periodically pull updated manifests from the Puppet master much like cf-agent/cf-execd does with promise bundles in CFE.

I'd say that if you configure puppet-agent to run every 10 minutes or so, it should pull down the latest changes and run, updating your VMs. I don't know how Puppet handles packages (RPM? deb?) management, but I'm sure that if your manifest says to install a list of packages, adding one to the list should invoke a package install, along with all the other provisioning directives - copy files, manage services, etc.

I'm guessing you could run puppet-agent as a daemon, or as a cron job.

The catch is - you have to be able to reach your Puppet master from the Vagrant systems, so they will not update unless you're connected to your VPN/network and can reach the master.